# Как ограничить ввод текста границами элемента Edittext

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Имеется активность, на которой по задумке, друг за другом в горизонтальном расположении находятся два элемента Edittext вложенных в Linear layout, у всех ширина контролируется двумя атрибутами:

```
layout_width="match_parent" и layout_weight=" "
```

Соответственно на разных экранах, ширина элемента будет разная. Вопрос: как ограничить ввод текста в Edittext рамками элемента? Иначе при вводе длинного текста, он заезжает за "видимые" границы элемента и текст тупо не видно.

Атрибут maxLength не подойдёт - он жестко регламентирует количество возможных символов. Перенос строки на следующую тоже нет, все в одну строку должно быть.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/ed_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Name_1" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/ed_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Name_2" />
        </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: А есть ли у этой затеи практическая ценность? Представьте, у владельца какого-нибудь планшета будет больше *возможностей* (в смысле написания более длинной строки) по сравнению с пользователем обычного смартфона. Это поле может быть полем ввода логина или пароля, полем поиска и проч. Неужели *эстетический* нюанс приложения должна пересилить равенство пользователей приложения? Или только с этой целью и создаётся оно?        *P.S. у разных букв разная ширина. Реализовать такое, думаю, стандартными средствами будет непросто*

Comment: Спасибо за внимание к моему вопросу! Я реально не могу понять, почему мой вопрос на многих форумах вызвал не желание помочь решить, а встречные вопросы. Если я так неправильно мыслю, тогда подскажите мне элемент, в которой пользователь сможешь ввести текст ровно на ширину его видимых границ, ну серьёзно зачем пользователю текст который залез за границы и его не видно?! ведь когда мы печатаем смс, оно переносится на новую строку, то есть приложение знает что достигнут край родит-го элемента и надо перенести,  моем случае нужно просто остановится, без переноса.

Comment: по поводу эстетичности, на вкус и цвет фломастеры разные, к тому же решение таких задач прибавляет, имхо, много опыта, я уже перелопатил кучу постов, и форумов, узнал попутно много нового)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, возможно использование `TextWatcher`:

```
final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    };
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (et.getLineCount() > 1) {
            et.setText(s.toString().substring(0, start));
            et.setSelection(start);
        };
    };
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    };
});
```

Если количество линий не будет равно 1, то убрать последний символ и перенести курсор в конец.

Comment: Василий, извините, есть время только комментарий написать, я обязательно вам отвечу, позже, как попробую ваш код!

Comment: Попробовал ваше решение, в чем дело не понял, но не отрабатывает, в атрибутах Edittext выставил maxLines = 2, singleLine = false, в надежде что без них в принципе нельзя перейти на другую строку, но нет. Подскажите,  у вас работает? пробовали?

Comment: @ДмитрийКутыркин, мой недочёт. Забыл сказать, что никакие атрибуты не нужны. Ведь иначе весь текст (видимый и невидимый) будет записываться в одну строку. Конечно, я проверял, у меня работает

Comment: @ДмитрийКутыркин, возможно, Вы вставляете текст из буфера обмена. Я обновил код, теперь он будет работать без ошибок (я нашёл одну).

Comment: Разве для такого решения не обязательно включить автоматический перенос? Или он по умолчанию включен? В ответе это не указано, а, кажется, это важно.

Comment: Василий, спасибо огромное, работает! Сначала не шло, пока я не перечитал ваш комментарий по поводу того, что никакие атрибуты не нужны, удалил android:inputType="textPersonName", после этого всё стало на свои места! Ещё раз спасибо.